# CGContextAddPath console error?

Tags: ios, console, cgcontext

In my app I get the following errors in the console:

```
May  1 22:06:59 iPhone-4S app[93660] <Error>: CGContextAddPath: invalid context 0x0
May  1 22:06:59 iPhone-4S app[93660] <Error>: clip: invalid context 0x0
```

The only areas in which this can be occurring is in either of the following two methods to resize or add rounded edges to a UIImage. Here are the methods:

```
- (UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {
    // Create a graphics image context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);

    // Tell the old image to draw in this new context, with the desired
    // new size
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];

    // Get the new image from the context
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    // End the context
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    // Return the new image.
    return newImage;
}

- (UIImage*)roundCorneredImage: (UIImage*)orig radius:(CGFloat) r {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(orig.size, NO, 0);
    [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:(CGRect){CGPointZero, orig.size} 
                                cornerRadius:r] addClip];
    [orig drawInRect:(CGRect){CGPointZero, orig.size}];
    UIImage* result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return result;
}
```

Both methods are called from within UIViewControllers and I am positive the UIImage is not nil.

Is there any reason for this to be happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

make sure the context size is not zero.

Comment: you mean the CGSize and/or radius parameter that I am feeding into it?

Comment: yes, if you call UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions with a Zero-size you will get exactly the same error, so i think your context is empty.